# How to use html tag in code behind?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I need to use html tags such as `<sup></sup>` in code behind without declaring anything in aspx page.

So far I've tried below:

```
string s = HtmlTextWriterTag.Sup.ToString("1");
```

Comment: Which HTML tag you want to use in code behind

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: What do you mean? try use Literal https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: add the namespace [System.Web.HtmlControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking

Comment: do you mean you wants to generate html dynamically through c# ? from code behind?

Comment: I have tried so far is:
string s=HtmlTextWriterTag.Sup.ToString("1");

Comment: You can use JQuery to do something like $('#element').html("<sup>----</sup>");

Comment: I cant use Jquery. Is it possible to edit my answer?

Comment: You mean edit your question?

Comment: No consider what I have tried and modify it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
var strVariable = "This is a string object";
strVariable = strVariable.sup();
```

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0h91cec2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you may use html gerneric contorls

`HtmlGenericControl sub= new HtmlGenericControl("sub");
  sub.Attributes.Add("class", "your-class");
  sub.ID = "subId";
  sub.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;`